# gdbus-monitor - interface `<none>`

Tags: glib, dbus, gdbus

Has the interface `<none>` in the `gdbus-monitor` output a special meaning?

What API call is required to create such a message using `GDbus` (`g_dbus_connection_register_object` does not allow to pass `NULL` as `GDBusInterfaceInfo *` and that seems to be the only to register a object to a path)

related: [dbus - register object to remote on interface NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357703/dbus-register-object-to-remote-on-interface-no-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into `dbus-monitor`'s [source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/tools/dbus-monitor.c?repo=platform--external--dbus&r=ade5c7ad33484a8b8f7c11591d4e80a83e7ff369) shows that it occures as soon as [`DBUS_EXPORT const char * dbus_message_get_interface    (   DBusMessage *   message )`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#ga1ad192bd4538cae556121a71b4e09d42) returns `NULL` (which is valid!, [but not according to the spec which requires minimum one `.` and two name chunks!!](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-names-interface) **EDIT:** A noteable exception are method calls which do not require the interface field of a message to be set http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-types).

---

`g_dbus_message_new_method_call (...)` allows `interface_` to be null. But that still only solves half the problems (sender). The receiver method seems to not exist for `interface_`s being `NULL`.

---

Turns out it is a bug, I did a source code investigation and filed a bug (including fix) https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706675

Answer (score 0):

client needs to know the interface name while subscribing g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe  to any signal else it will listen to all interfaces hence inefficient.
Interface is required to bind methods and signals in single entity mentioned in server introspection xml file.

Comment: a) this question is over 1.5 years old, why answer now with
b) an answer that does not solve nor explain the root cause.